# Marginal likelihood (or Bayes factor) when true model *not* in the set

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, bayes-factors

The marginal likelihood (or Bayes factor) method to perform model comparison, based on $\Pr(\text{data}|\text{model})$, assumes that the true model is the model set (*closed world* assumption).

What happens when the true model is *not* in the model set?

I assume that the method would report a high Bayes factor aka posterior probability for the model within the set which is "closest" to the true model, according to some metric. If so, which metric? My guess is that it can't be KL-divergence, otherwise this would be identical to predictive metrics such leave-one-out (or approximations thereof; e.g., AIC).

The reason why I am asking is that one of the argument I often read against marginal likelihoods (or Bayes factors) is the assumption that the true model is in the model set. However, if comparison via marginal likelihood minimizes the KL-divergence between the chosen model and the true model (not in the set), I do not see how it differs from the predictive methods.

For this question, let's forget about other issues of the marginal likelihood / Bayes factors approach (such as prior sensitivity).

Comment: Yes it is the model that is closest in KL-divergence. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "predictive metrics", but Bayes Factors simply report the ratio of the density (or mass) of the data under the prior predictive distribution, so perhaps it is not surprising that it is identical to "predictive metrics"?

Comment: @jaradniemi: Thanks for the comment. By "predictive metrics" I mean AIC or leave-one-out cross-validation, which are shown under some conditions to minimize the KL-divergence between the chosen model and the true model (I thought it was standard nomenclature -- how would you call them?). The reason why I am asking is that one of the argument I often read against Bayes factors is that BF assumes that the true model is in the model set. However, if it minimizes the KL-divergence between the chosen model and the true model (not in the set), I don't see how it differs from the predictive methods.